# All maven dependencies are shown right in project folder rather than in a maven library in a java project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

I imported one project form a git repository. I imported it as a Java project and the project has many maven dependencies.

After I executed maven install all the dependencies are showing under the project menu, but for other who checked out the project all the dependencies are showing in a maven library in the project.

We checked out the code from the same repository and we have the same settings for maven installed in our computers. What could went wrong in here? I checked the maven settings in eclipse and the setting.xml file and they are both identical (except some path names which differ on different machines.)

Answer (score 0):

`Right click over the project > Configure > Convert to Maven project`. It should be displayed correctly, after this.